# alternating series test convergence proof with Cauchy criterion

Tags: real-analysis

If we have a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and this sequence is decreasing and converges to $0$, how can I show that for the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}a_n$$
the sequence of partial sums
$$s_n=a_1-a_2+a_3-a_4+a_5+\ldots+(-1)^{n+1}a_n$$
is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: how i can use symbols like that?, thank to write with more clarity.

Comment: Alternating series test. Search for it. Convergence of the series would imply that $S_n\to L$ as $n\to\infty$. And convegence would imply cauchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\forall n\geqslant k,\ \forall m\geqslant k,\ |s_n-s_m|\leqslant a_{k+1}$$

Comment: thank you, my error was don't see that all terms in the sequence are greater or equal to zero.